# How to calculate Intersection over Union for 2 rectangles with the different orientation in python?

Tags: python, math, tensorflow, geometry

My ground truth is oriented rectangle. How can I calculate IoU between my output rectangle and ground truth?
Ground truth has these parameters: x_centre,y_centre,height,width,angle of orientation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is using some library providing [boolean operations over polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_operations_on_polygons). Choose one that has Python bindings.

[Clipper library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/polyclipping/?source=navbar)  features:

> Line and polygon clipping - intersection, union, difference & xor
>   The library is written in Delphi, C++, C# and Python
>   Third-party modules for Perl, Ruby and Python languages

If you want to make calculations 'by hands', consider O'Rourke algorithm ([free code for his book is here](http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/books/compgeom.html)) or [Plante's approach](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~plante/compGeom/algorithm.html) to get intersection, and do some research to extend these methods and find union.

Comment: Even this library is useful : **http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#geometric-objects**